# iPad 1, how to run code?

Tags: ios

The iPad 1 update past `iOS 5`. When I try to run my app from Xcode on it, it says

> Xcode cannot run on the selected device. No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

What do I need to do to be able to run my app on this iPad?

Comment: What have you selected for "deployment target" in your project?

Comment: Also, if your device does not support the latest version of an app, the latest compatible version will be installed provided that such a version exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can edit your project as follow.
[image]